# Update table columns that changed only with php

Tags: php, sql-update

I have seen some really old posts that somehow address my question but they werent answered.

I usually update mysql tables regardless of a column's change. However, in this new project am starting to work on, I am concerned about that practice. The update is per single row mostly but updates do happen very often.

What would be the proper way to handle the case? Have hidden fields per columns then compare with php or Javascript? Can MySQL be smarted to doing something like this? Which costs more: writing to mysql table even when a column needs no update or to check with php for every update?

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to update the columns that need to be updated instead of updating all the columns where the value and the new value is the same?

Comment: MySQL ___is___ that smart: if no columns have changed, then it doesn't update. You still have the overhead of sending the request to MySQL, but it won't actually change the row if the column values are the same

Comment: On the other side of the equation, many ORMs maintain a old model values for comparison when you issue an update/save request, and don't even send the request to the database if there's no change